# Recommended computer for PUBG

Tags: pc

Recommended computer for PUBG (budget $900)；
I hope the price performance is high.
Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

CPU:AMD R5 2600X
motherboard:MSI-MORTAR B450
VC:MSI-R580 8g
SSD:PLEXTOR M9PeGn 512g
HDD:SEAGATE 1T
RAM:CORSAIR 3000 8G*2
power:CoolerMaster GX550